# Django: how to use reverse() in any class

Tags: python, django

I have a class file something like myclass.py in project/myapp/myclass.py
how can I use reverse() in there? I can't find any information how to import urlConf! without getting urls, i have exception NoReverseMatch

in fact django-jqgrid using this kind of method in their example: https://github.com/gerry/django-jqgrid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always import `django.core.urlresolvers.reverse` and pass it necessary `args` and `kwargs` to reverse.

The reverse defnition is:

```
reverse(viewname[, urlconf=None, args=None, kwargs=None, current_app=None])
```

In your view you can always do:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

def myview(request):
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('arch-summary', args=[1945]))
```

Refer [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#reverse) for more.